# is there any wrong with the "L->next=NULL" in the LinkedListInit, LinkedListCreateH method?

Tags: c++

I'm setting up a new C++ console application, but it said that I have some problem with the using of NULL pointer in my program. The inition of `strong text`linkedlist L and Node *p can not be found in my code. The return value of the scanf can not be found in my program.

This is a new C++ window application.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef int ElemType;
typedef struct Node {
    ElemType data;
    struct Node* next;
}Node, * LinkedList;

LinkedList LinkedListInit() {
    Node* L;
    L = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (L == NULL)printf("申请内存空间失败/n");
    L->next = NULL;
}
LinkedList LinkedListCreateH() {
    Node* L;
    L = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    L->next = NULL;
    ElemType x;
    while (scanf("%d", &x) != EOF) {
        Node* p;
        p = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        p->data = x;
        p->next = L->next;
        L->next = p;
    }
    return L;
}
LinkedList LinkedListCreatT() {
    Node* L;
    L = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    L->next = NULL;
    Node* r;
    r = L;
    ElemType x;
    while (scanf("%d", &x) != EOF) {
        Node* p;
        p = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        p->data = x;
        r->next = p;
        r = p;
    }
    r->next = NULL;
    return L;
}
LinkedList LinkedListInsert(LinkedList L, int i, ElemType e) {
    Node* pre;
    pre = L;
    int tempi = 0;
    for (tempi = 1; tempi < i; tempi++)
        pre = pre->next;
    Node* p;
    p->data = e;
    p->next = pre->next;
    pre->next = p;
}
LinkedList LinkedListDelete(LinkedList L, ElemType e) {
    Node* p, * pre;
    p = L->next;

    while (p->data != e) { pre = p; p = p->next; }
    pre->next = p->next;
    free(p);
    return L;
}

int main() {
    LinkedList list, start;
    LinkedListInit();
    printf("请输入单链表的数据：");
    for (start = list->next; start != NULL; start = start->next)printf("%d", start->data);
    printf("/n");
    int i;
    ElemType x;
    printf("请输入插入数据位置：");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("请输入插入数据的值：");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    LinkedListInsert(list, i, x);
    for (start = list->next; start != NULL; start = start->next)printf("%d", start->data);
    printf("/n");
    printf("请输入要删除元素的值：");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    LinkedListDelete(list, x);
    for (start = list->next; start != NULL; start = start->next)printf("%d", start->data);
    printf("/n");
    return 0;

}
```

I expect to the output of 0,9....,but it is 0 now

Comment: Doesn't the compiler complain about all functions that are supposed to return something but really doesn't return anything?

Comment: `L = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node))` - *Don't* use `malloc` in C++. And that C-style cast is also pretty nasty.

Comment: Do you have a strong reason, why you implement a list by yourself and use malloc? If not, please use std::vector, std::list or whatever fits your needs. currently your are using C.

Comment: If `malloc()` returns `NULL`, the `L` will also be `NULL`, and the assignment `L->next = NULL` will have undefined behaviour.   Nothing in your function correctly deals with `malloc()` returning `NULL`.    Also, the function has a non-`void` return type, and no `return` statement, so returning causes undefined behaviour.    Other things wrong in your code are using `malloc()` in C++ (strongly discouraged) and trying to implement a linked list from scratch rather than using the `std::list` which is part of the standard C++ library.

Comment: This code must be producing a ton of warnings (you have warnings enabled, right?), you should probably try to fix all of them first.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple functions that have non-void return types but have no return statement.

`LinkedList LinkedListInit() {`

and

`LinkedListInsert`

That's undefined behavior and after that, all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
    LinkedList list, start;
    LinkedListInit();
    printf("请输入单链表的数据：");
    for (start = list->next; // <- blam
```

`list` is not initialized to anything, so accessing `list->next` should crash.
That's assuming you compile in C mode (which you can, there is nothing ++ about this code), if you compile it as C++, you will most likely get burned earlier by what xaxxon says, because the compiler will not generate a return instruction at the end of LinkedListInit and you start executing random garbage (at least that's what gcc and clang tend to do).

Not returning a value you promised is somewhat legal in C (not in C++), but still a bad idea.